# FatalErrorException in Gettext.php line 187

Tags: laravel-5, fatal-error

I downloaded and installed Laravel 5.0. When creating a clean project with composer, it seems to work all fine, I get a screen that says "LARAVEL" and so on.

Then I forked a repository of a colleague for a website which he has online. But when I try to run that site "as-is" in my environment I first get an error that says undefined function "Illuminate.... and so forth". I updated all dependencies and now the error is gone. Instead I get the following screen:

[image: Image or error messages]

What does this mean? Google and SO both don't seem to know this error.